# jQuery Suckerfish no animation

Tags: jquery, animation, suckerfish

I use jQuery and the suckfish plugin for a menu but i don't want any animation when the submenu is showing.

I have the speed set on 0 but still there is some milliseconds between the head menu hover and the sub menu.

How can i disable the animation totally?

Comment: Maybe you could do It without the plugin since no animation is needed? Give this a shot: http://be.twixt.us/jquery/suckerFish.php substituting fadeIn('fast') with show()

Comment: Thnx Micropino :)... that will do the trick!

Comment: :) Ok I posted it as an answer... Would you like to accept It? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do It without the plugin since no animation is needed?

If you can, try [this code](http://be.twixt.us/jquery/suckerFish.php). 
Make sure you substitute `fadeIn('fast')` with just `show()`.